# Вывод случайного изображения по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

При нажатии на кнопку должна выводится 5 случайных картинок из трех разных массивов картинок. Как это сделать?

*Я только начинающий и поэтому не знаю с чего начать и как действовать.*

Comment: В чем именно сложность возникает? Сами пробовали хоть что-нибудь написать?

Comment: Начните с чего-нибудь и действуйте как-нибудь, а когда возникнет более конкретный вопрос - можно будет задать его здесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать следующим образом. Добавить все картинки в один массив:

```
List<Image> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(list1));
l.addAll(Arrays.asList(list2));
l.addAll(Arrays.asList(list3));
```

где `list1`, `list2`, `list3` Ваши 3 массива с картинками. Перемешать все картинки случайным образом.

```
Collections.shuffle(l);
```

И в конце отобрать, допустим, первые 5 картинок

```
List<Image> imagesToShow = l.subList(0, 6);
```

Для того, чтобы это все сделать по нажатию на кнопку, нужно добавить обработчик события на эту кнопку, предположим `button`.

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {// Код, представленный выше} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Объединяете 3 массива с картинками в один, делаете функцию которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку. В ней узнаете длину массива L и в цикле создаете 5 рандомных чисел от 0 до L, эти 5 чисел и будут индексами случайных картинок которые в функции должны куда то выводится. 
Информации как сделать слушатель событий на кнопку что бы что то выполнялось, полно в интернете, от статей с описанием нужных методов, до видео на ютубе 
Для большей конкретики нужен более конкретный вопрос. 
Куда должны выводится картинки? в чем они отображаются? какой их размер?